# AWS - An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm unable to read from S3 in my lambda. Public access to the bucket is blocked. Is there something in here that looks out of order?
Here's a snippet from the yml

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - 's3:GetObject'
            - 's3:PutObject'
          Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"
```

Here's the code failing:

```
def check_s3(user):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket="my_bucket", Key=user)
    data = json.loads(obj['Body'].read())
    return data
```

And here's the IAM role permissions

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

After googling around for quite some time trying different things I feel like it looks as what everyone recommends when seeing this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is almost certainly answered in https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403

Comment: Is the S3 bucket encrypted using KMS? If so, you might need to add extra permissions to use the associated KMS key.

Comment: In your YAML you have `Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"`, but in your IAM policy you have `"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*", "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"]`. Why are they different? For `GetObject` and `PutObject`, the resource ARN should be the one ending in `/*`.